# Sum of products boolean algebra with 3 inputs

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have the following expression

```
A'.B.C + B'.A.C + C'.B.C + C'.A'.B'
```

I've tried taking out some variables and applying demorgan laws and it didnt, I also tried XOR but it would result in `C.A.B` instead, any suggestions or is completely simplified, I was able to get it down to `C.(A XOR B) + C'(B.C + A'.B')`, but I remember there being a better solution.

Note: ' means NOT, . and, + or

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Note: you can use the software called "Logic Friday" for searching for minimized expressions (in this case just remove the $C'BC$ and it is minimized as sum of products). You can also select the logical gates you want and it tries to map the expression to them.

Comment: should be the third term C´.B.A?

Comment: With the suggestion by user376343 you can reduce it to $D=B\oplus C$ and $AD+(A==D)$